Background color is not filling the entire width of the section when the screen is resized
I was trying to recreate amazon header but i am facing a issue when the window is being resized, background color of my header is not filling up the entire width of the screen. i am attaching my html and css, can someone let me know what i am doing wrong.


*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}
.left{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.logo{
    padding: 0 12px;
}
.logo_img{
    width: 120px;
}

.location{
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 12px;
}

.locationHead{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.update{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.mid{
    width: 1100px;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1057px;
}

.categoriesButton{
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-width: 55px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.searchBar{
    flex: 1;
    height: 41px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
.searchBar::placeholder{
    padding: 0px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.searchButton{
    min-width: 45px;
    background-color: rgb(178, 157, 75);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.right{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.language{
    color: white;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.languageSelect{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.languageSelect p{
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.languageItems{
    display: none;
}

.signin{
    color: white;
    margin-right: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.top{
    font-size: 14px;
}
.bottom{
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.accountItems{
    display: none;
}

.orders{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.cart{
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
        integrity="sha384-4LISF5TTJX/fLmGSxO53rV4miRxdg84mZsxmO8Rx5jGtp/LbrixFETvWa5a6sESd" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section class="header">

        <div class="left">

            <span class="logo">
                <img class="logo_img" src="amazon/logo.png" alt="Amazon.in" class="logo">
            </span>

            <div class="location">
                <p class="locationHead">Delivering to XYZ 123456</p>
                <p class="update"><i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i> Update location</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="mid">
            

                <button class="categoriesButton">All <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-short"></i></button>

                <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Serch Amazon.in">

                <button class="searchButton"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>

            
        </div>

        <div class="right">

            <div class="language">
                <div class="languageSelect">
                    <i class="bi bi-map"></i>
                    <p>EN</p>
                    <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-short"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="languageItems">
                    <p>language1</p>
                    <p>language2</p>
                    <p>language3</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="signin">
                <span class="top">Hello, sign in</span>
                <div class="accountAction">
                <span class="bottom">Accounts & Lists<i class="bi bi-arrow-down-short"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="accountItems">
                    <p>item1</p>
                    <p>item2</p>
                    <p>item3</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="orders">
                <span class="top">Returns</span>
                <span class="bottom">& Orders</span>
            </div>

            <div class="cart"><i class="bi bi-cart"></i>&nbsp;Cart</div>

        </div>

    </section>



Here is the header in full window mode]And here is the header when the window width is around 700px

The children of .header are overflowing and expanding the width of your document over the 100%. Add overflow: hidden to .header to fix it or flex-wrap: wrap.

When using flex-wrap: wrap, the overflowing elements are simply moved to the next line, whereas overflow: hidden removes the content. It behaves properly when I use overflow: scroll in the header. However, putting the full page in another div does not seem like a good approach to me.
